# app crash first SMS received and SMS broadcaster doesn't get called, how come?

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to build a simple app that can notify if there is a sms incoming. Just get the broadcaster to work, but what happens is that my app crashes when I get a SMS, and then next time it get a SMS nothing happens. I don't have any error message to go after or show either.

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.studerande.upg62_b">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".IncomingSmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

my broadcaster class which extends BroadcastReceiver. Excuse my Toasts but I just wanted to see if it was running but it isn't..

```
    package com.example.studerande.upg62_b;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Studerande on 2017-03-18.
 */

public class IncomingSmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null && SMS_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            final SmsMessage smsMessage = extractSmsMessage(intent);
            processMessage(context, smsMessage);

        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "yo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private SmsMessage extractSmsMessage(final Intent intent) {

        final Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
        final Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
        String format = pudsBundle.getString("format");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0], format);
            return smsMessage;
        }
        else {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
            return smsMessage;
        }


    }

    private void processMessage(final Context context, final SmsMessage smsMessage) {
        // Do something interesting here
        Toast.makeText(context, "yo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

MainActivity. You don't need to do anything here if I understood it correctly right?

```
    package com.example.studerande.upg62_b;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem is because of the API version. The broadcaster works in phone that has API 22 or below, but not in the later versions because of the new permission-handling that was introduced. So I need to ask permission before I can read SMS. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html